# Send data to Qthread when in have changes in GUI windows pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

Hi i have Qthread which have to wait some minutes which user input from MainWindow
the some Qthread code

```
class Worker(QThread):
  list_of_dict_signals = pyqtSignal(list)
  def __init__(self):
    QThread.__init__(self)
    self.running = False

  def run(self):
    self.running = True
    while self.running:
        info = self.check_info()
        print(info)
        self.list_of_dict_signals.emit(info)
        self.sleep(value that user have to input in main window)
```

Some code of main window:

```
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.myworker = Worker()
    self.myworker.list_of_dict_signals.connect(self.onDataFromThread)

    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_start)
    self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.on_stop)




  def on_start(self):
    if not self.myworker.isRunning():
        #need to send data from self.ui.spinBox.value() each time when user press start
        self.myworker.start()
```

Thx

Comment: You could explain me better, I do not understand anything. :P

Comment: There is a `self.ui.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)` in GUI i have to take the `value` of it and send to `Qthread` in may case `Worker`, when user press `self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_start)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to create a function that updates the sleep time:

Thread:

```
class Worker(QThread):
    list_of_dict_signals = pyqtSignal(list)
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.running = False
        self.time_sleep = 0.1 # default value

    def setTime(self, val):
        self.time_sleep = val

    def run(self):
        ...
        self.sleep(self.time_sleep)
```

GUI:

```
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    ...

    def on_start(self):
        if not self.myworker.isRunning():
            self.myworker.setTime(self.ui.spinBox.value())
            self.myworker.start()
```